# Why does my string output have a missing letter?

Tags: python

I don't understand the output

```
INPUT
name = 'World'
line = '-'
for char in name:
    print(line)
    line = line + char

OUTPUT
-
-W
-Wo
-Wor
-Worl
```

why is there no -World

very confused. first day learning python. no prior knowledge of any language

Comment: Think about the order in which things happen in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're only concatenating `line` and `name` after printing `line`. So, on the last iteration of the loop, it prints "-Worl" and *then* adds the 'd' to `line`. If you print `line` again outside the loop, the output will be "-World".

You can fix this by changing the order of the lines inside the loop to:

```py
for char in name:
    line = line + char
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are printing the line before adding the character.

If you want to print the whole word you need to set the line variable before printing it.

```
name = 'World'
line = '-'
for char in name:
    line = line + char
    print(line)
```

I assume this is for an exercise, but if you just want to print the word with the dash in front of it, you don't need the loop, and can instead write `print(line + name)`.